# Remote debugging NodeJS Container on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, docker, amazon-ec2

Running a NodeJS Docker Container on an EC2 instance, I'm trying to remote debug it, but keep getting "connection refused" from the instance.

What I've tried -

- Opening ports in EC2 security groups
- Exposing ports in Dockerfile, both the port the app is listening on and the debug port
- Forwarding the port within the Docker run command using the -p flag
- Making sure the app is accessible directly through the port it's configured to listen to

After trying all of these, the debug port is still inaccessible by the remote debugger or even telnet.
Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: What are the ports in question? Is the firewall active on the EC2 server? Can you try a simple http app on the port you are trying to hit (e.g., simple node or python server - first on the host, then in a container)?

Comment: Are you certain you are actually activating the debugger via `node --debug`? Do you see the console output indicating it is listening on port 5858?

Comment: @ldg: The ports I'm trying to access are 3000 for the app and 3010 for debug. Both are open via EC2 firewall and were checked by running python's SimpleHTTPServer natively and as a container forwarding ports to host (again, using the -p flag)

Comment: @PeterLyons: I'm pretty sure, I'm running the app using nodemon with the debug flag. It worked using a local container, so I'm having a hard time understanding why it doesn't work remotely since the ports are open.

Comment: having this same issue with elastic beanstalk and ECS single container.  I cannot seem to ever get a port open.  I think the docker ports are not being exposed at all